# El POST de Angular 9 no me envía parametros

Tags: php, angular, typescript, post, http

Estoy intentando realizar una petición POST a mi servidor con PHP.
Las peticiones get que empleo funcionan correctamente, pero las post fallan a la hora de enviar los parámetros.

Un ejemplo de mi GET:

```
  getRole(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get( location.origin + "/demeter_control/PHP/services/servicioDarRol.php");
  }
```

(Me suscribo al GET)

```
this.conexionBDService.getRole().subscribe(
    result => {
        $('.dropdownRole').append('<option value="" selected disabled hidden></option>');
        for(var i = 0; i<result.length; i++){
            if(result[i]["id"]!=null){
                $('.dropdownRole').append('<option class="dropdown-item" value="'+result[i]["id"]+'">'+result[i]["nombre"]+'</option>');
            }
        }
    },
    error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
    }
);
```

Mi POST:

```
  registerNewUser(jsonUser): Observable<any>{
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'authorization': '750e8b43e5ed564462c90ef0d382db26'
      })
    };
    console.log("Segundo typescript ->" + jsonUser);
    return this.http.post<any>( location.origin + "/demeter_control/PHP/services/registerUser.php", {aaa:"hola"}, httpOptions);
  }
```

(Me suscribo a mi POST):

```
this.conexionBDService.registerNewUser(JSON.stringify($("#myform").serializeArray())).subscribe(
    result => {
        console.log("Primer typescript 0 ->" + result);
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error);
        $(".respuestaWarning").css("display", "block");
    }
);
```

Como veis solo quiero enviar la variable **aaa** de momento, pero ni eso recibe.
Por lado del PHP gasto:

echo $_POST["aaa"];

Y esto es lo que me devuelve la terminal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Luego de poder enviar la variable que he creado aaa le pasaré los datos que contiene JSON.stringify($("#myform").serializeArray()) pero por el momento me conformo con haber podido recibir algo.

Comment: Buenas, para enviar un dato en un post tienes que enviar un objeto json. Por lo que si en tu back quieres recibir aaa tienes que enviar {aaa:'hola'}. En el código que muestras solo estas enviando 'hola' por lo que es normal que en el back no te lo pille.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, he agregado tu sugerencia y no ha cambiado nada, el codigo sigue sin funcionar, el problema ha de estar en otra cosa, pero bueno es saberlo que solo puedo pasar JSON

Comment: Modifica el código para ver el cambio que has realizado

Comment: ya está modificado

Comment: Solo ahora esta línea le mando un JSON:                                          
return this.http.post<any>( location.origin + "/demeter_control/PHP/services/registerUser.php", {aaa:"hola"}, httpOptions);

Comment: Y si haces en el back print_r($_POST); para ver que resultado te esta enviando el front

Comment: printea Array(), vamos que por lo visto no llega nada de nada

Answer (score 0):

La llamada Angular es correcta, creo que el problema está en PHP, no conozco mucho de PHP pero creo que cuando la petición es en formato JSON hay que hacer alguna conversión:

```
// Convierte los que llega en formato JSON a un String
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

// Generamos un objeto PHP que podemos iterar
$data = json_decode($json);

// Los parámetros deben poderse acceder ahora
$data["aaa"]
```

Fuente: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-receive-json-post-with-php/